# Data structure with fast look up by index and element removal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, abstract-data-type, array-splice

Summary:
I have a piece of code which wants to initialize an Array, then iteratively look up an index, get the value, then remove the element at that index, shifting all the values above down an index. Doing this with a normal array is θ(n^2). I want to if there is a better approach than what I came up with.

Abstract data type needs to support:
Initialization with all the data known at the start.
Finding the value of an index.
Removing an index, filling the gap by shifting all elements after to the left.

The Data Structure I came up with:
A full binary tree with the 'indices' at the leafs and interior nodes storing the number of leaves that are filled.
Initialization is pretty easy and is nlogn
Indexing is done by from the root checking its children's counts and recursing to the correct child logn.
Once you are at a leaf removal is done by nulling out the data and then going back up the tree decrimenting all the counts by 1 logn.

With an nlogn initilization and n index/removals which are logn the overall runtime is nlogn.

Comment: Feels very much like a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). Initialization is `O(n)`. Otherwise the reasoning looks correct. Note that the insertion at the index is also `O(log n)`.

Comment: What you’re proposing here is closely related to Fenwick trees and order statistic trees. Seems like a great approach!

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking maybe we can use a hashmap with a double linked list

on initialization, populate the hashmap with given array value as key and use pointer(iterator) to the linked list node as the value of the hashmap, populate double linked list too

when trying to remove, find the pointer based on value using the hashmap, and remove the node in the linked list

this way, initialization is O(n) and operation is O(1)